# Usage of algorithm inside animateinline creates unexplainable offset

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

**Update**: Using `pgfmathsetmacro` in combination with an actual function, inside `tikzpicture` seems to be the issue. Some of the white space can be circumvented by the usage of `\relax` inside `\pgfmathsetmacro`, but this produces a random `@` in the tikzpicture.

---

I made an algorithm inside `pgfmath` which I intend to use inside my animation (see below). For some reason a weird offset to the right is created only when I use this algorithm (`qnorm` inside `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` in preamble). Why is this happening?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UK5Te9M.png?1]

I believe it's self-explanatory that the alignment of the animated tikzpicture is completely wrong in the above picture.

To understand what's happening, try setting the values to:

`\pgfmathsetmacro\static{10}` and 
  `\pgfmathsetmacro\qqq{14}`

I simply cannot explain why the calculated value produces this behaviour contrary to the an approximation set directly inside `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normal}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
%
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{qnorm}{4}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{#1}
    \edef\p{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{#2}
    \edef\mu{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{#3}
    \edef\sigma{\pgfmathresult}
    %
    \pgfmathparse{\sigma < 0 ? 1 : 0}           
    \edef\sigma@neg{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\sigma == 0 ? 1 : 0}          
    \edef\sigma@zero{\pgfmathresult}
    %
    \pgfmathparse{\p - .5}                  
    \edef\q{\pgfmathresult}
    %
    \pgfmathparse{abs(\q) <= .425 ? 1 : 0}      
    \edef\q@i{\pgfmathresult}               
    %
    \pgfmathparse{                      
      \q@i ?                        
        .180625 - \q * \q               
      :                     
        sqrt(-ln(min(\p,(1-\p))))                        
    }
    \edef\r@{\pgfmathresult}
   % 
    \pgfmathparse{\q@i ? 
      \r@ 
    : 
      (\r@ <= 5 ?  
        \r@ - 1.6 %
      : 
        \r@ - 5
      )}
    \edef\r{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\q@i ? 
    (\q * (((((((\r * 2509.0809287301226727 +
                       33430.575583588128105) * \r + 67265.770927008700853) * \r +
                     45921.953931549871457) * \r + 13731.693765509461125) * \r +
                   1971.5909503065514427) * \r + 133.14166789178437745) * \r +
                 3.387132872796366608)
            / (((((((\r * 5226.495278852854561 +
                     28729.085735721942674) * \r + 39307.89580009271061) * \r +
                   21213.794301586595867) * \r + 5394.1960214247511077) * \r +
                 687.1870074920579083) * \r + 42.313330701600911252) * \r + 1.))
                                    : ( \r@ <= 5 ?  
                                        ((((((((\r * 7.7454501427834140764e-4 +     %
                       .0227238449892691845833) * \r + .24178072517745061177) *     %
                     \r + 1.27045825245236838258) * \r +                        %
                    3.64784832476320460504) * \r + 5.7694972214606914055) *     %
                  \r + 4.6303378461565452959) * \r +                        %
                 1.42343711074968357734)                                %
                / (((((((\r *                                       %
                         1.05075007164441684324e-9 + 5.475938084995344946e-4) *     %
                        \r + .0151986665636164571966) * \r +                    %
                       .14810397642748007459) * \r + .68976733498510000455) *       %
                     \r + 1.6763848301838038494) * \r +                     %
                    2.05319162663775882187) * \r + 1))                      %
                                        :       
                                        ((((((((\r * 2.01033439929228813265e-7 +
                       2.71155556874348757815e-5) * \r +
                      .0012426609473880784386) * \r + .026532189526576123093) *
                    \r + .29656057182850489123) * \r +
                   1.7848265399172913358) * \r + 5.4637849111641143699) *
                 \r + 6.6579046435011037772)
                / (((((((\r *
                         2.04426310338993978564e-15 + 1.4215117583164458887e-7)*
                        \r + 1.8463183175100546818e-5) * \r +
                       7.868691311456132591e-4) * \r + .0148753612908506148525)
                     * \r + .13692988092273580531) * \r +
                    .59983220655588793769) * \r + 1.))
                    )
                 }
    \edef\val{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\q@i ? \val :
    (\q > 0 ? \val : -\val)}                    %
    \edef\@tmp{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\p > 1 ? sqrt(-1) :
      (\p < 0 ? sqrt(-1) :
        \sigma@neg ? sqrt(-1) :             %
         (\sigma@zero ? \mu :               %
           (#4 ? \mu+\sigma*\@tmp :         
                     \mu-\sigma*\@tmp)              % 
         )
       )
    }
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\samplesize{7}\relax
  \let\mean\relax\newcommand\mean{9}\relax
  \let\sd\relax\newcommand\sd{3}\relax
  \let\lowertail\relax\newcommand\lowertail{0}\relax
\begin{figure}[ht]
\capstart
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{15}
  \multiframe{15}{ik=1+2}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      hide y axis,
      axis lines*=center, 
      axis on top,
      no markers, 
      domain=4:20, 
      samples=4*\samplesize-7,
      xlabel=\empty, 
      ylabel=\empty,
      every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
      every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
      width=.8\linewidth,
      height=.3\linewidth,
      xmin = 4, xmax=20,
      xtick=, ytick=\empty,
      enlargelimits=false, 
      clip=false
  ]
  \pgfmathsetmacro\result{1/((\ik/25+.65)^2+(ln(\ik/25+.65)^2+1.5))/1.2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\static{qnorm(0.05,\mean,\sd,\lowertail)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\qqq{qnorm(\result,\mean,\sd,\lowertail)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\colorq{(.1+.2*\ik/180)*100}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\colorr{(.3+.55*\ik/180)*100}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\colort{(.9-.8*\ik/180)*100}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\colors{(.85-.55*\ik/180)*100}
  \node at (axis cs:5,0.2) {};
  \node at (axis cs:10.25,0.025) {\ifnum\ik>75{\textcolor{red}{waarschijnlijk een effect! $\rightarrow$}}\else{waarschijnlijk geen effect}\fi};
  \node at (axis cs:\qqq,{1/(\sd*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\qqq-\mean)^2)/(2*\sd^2))+.02}) {\ifnum\ik<75$\downarrow$\else\textcolor{red}{$\downarrow$}\fi}; 
  \path[name path=line] (axis cs:\static,0) -- (axis cs:\static,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}*1.1);
  \addplot [name path=normaal,very thick,cyan!85!black!50] {normal(\mean,\sd)};
  \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
  \addplot[cyan!\colort!red!\colorq,draw=cyan!\colors!red!\colorr,thick]   fill between[of=normaal and axis,soft clip={domain=\qqq:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}];
  \node at (axis cs:{\mean+1.65*\sd},{.055-.003*\sd^.5-.0015*\sd^2}) [pin=45:$\alpha$] {}; 
  \node at (axis cs:{\mean*.85},{1/(\sd*sqrt(2*pi))-.015}) [pin=135:$H_0$] {};
  \node at (axis cs:{4+\mean+1.65*\sd},{.08+.055-.003*\sd^.5-.0015*\sd^2}) [rectangle,draw=blue!60,fill=cyan!10] {\ifnum\ik<75$p=\result$\else\textcolor{red}{$p=\result$}\fi}; 
  \path[name intersections={of=line and normaal, by={interp}}];
  \draw[draw=red!80!black] (axis cs:\static,0) -- (interp);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\caption{De verdeling die hoort bij een nulhypothese en een aantal mogelijke meetresultaten (weergegeven door het pijltje) - wanneer je meetresultaat erg afwijkt van de aanname waarbij er geen effect zou plaatsvinden, is er dus waarschijnlijk kans op een effect}\label{fig:p.waarde.anim}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have plenty of unprotected end-of-lines in the definition of `\qnorm`; spaces are ignored in the argument of `\pgfmathparse`, but not in other places of `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normal}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{qnorm}{4}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    \edef\p{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{#2}%
    \edef\mu{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{#3}%
    \edef\sigma{\pgfmathresult}%
    %
    \pgfmathparse{\sigma < 0 ? 1 : 0}%
    \edef\sigma@neg{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{\sigma == 0 ? 1 : 0}%
    \edef\sigma@zero{\pgfmathresult}%
    %
    \pgfmathparse{\p - .5}%       
    \edef\q{\pgfmathresult}%
    %
    \pgfmathparse{abs(\q) <= .425 ? 1 : 0}%
    \edef\q@i{\pgfmathresult}%
    %
    \pgfmathparse{
      \q@i ?
        .180625 - \q * \q
      :
        sqrt(-ln(min(\p,(1-\p))))
    }%
    \edef\r@{\pgfmathresult}%
   % 
    \pgfmathparse{\q@i ?
      \r@
    :
      (\r@ <= 5 ?
        \r@ - 1.6 %
      :
        \r@ - 5
      )}%
    \edef\r{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{\q@i ? 
    (\q * (((((((\r * 2509.0809287301226727 +
                       33430.575583588128105) * \r + 67265.770927008700853) * \r +
                     45921.953931549871457) * \r + 13731.693765509461125) * \r +
                   1971.5909503065514427) * \r + 133.14166789178437745) * \r +
                 3.387132872796366608)
            / (((((((\r * 5226.495278852854561 +
                     28729.085735721942674) * \r + 39307.89580009271061) * \r +
                   21213.794301586595867) * \r + 5394.1960214247511077) * \r +
                 687.1870074920579083) * \r + 42.313330701600911252) * \r + 1.))
                                    : ( \r@ <= 5 ?  
                                        ((((((((\r * 7.7454501427834140764e-4 +
                       .0227238449892691845833) * \r + .24178072517745061177) *%
                     \r + 1.27045825245236838258) * \r +
                    3.64784832476320460504) * \r + 5.7694972214606914055) *
                  \r + 4.6303378461565452959) * \r +
                 1.42343711074968357734)
                / (((((((\r *
                         1.05075007164441684324e-9 + 5.475938084995344946e-4) *
                        \r + .0151986665636164571966) * \r +
                       .14810397642748007459) * \r + .68976733498510000455) *
                     \r + 1.6763848301838038494) * \r +
                    2.05319162663775882187) * \r + 1))
                                        :       
                                        ((((((((\r * 2.01033439929228813265e-7 +
                       2.71155556874348757815e-5) * \r +
                      .0012426609473880784386) * \r + .026532189526576123093) *
                    \r + .29656057182850489123) * \r +
                   1.7848265399172913358) * \r + 5.4637849111641143699) *
                 \r + 6.6579046435011037772)
                / (((((((\r *
                         2.04426310338993978564e-15 + 1.4215117583164458887e-7)*
                        \r + 1.8463183175100546818e-5) * \r +
                       7.868691311456132591e-4) * \r + .0148753612908506148525)
                     * \r + .13692988092273580531) * \r +
                    .59983220655588793769) * \r + 1.))
                    )
                 }%
    \edef\val{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{\q@i ? \val :
    (\q > 0 ? \val : -\val)}%
    \edef\@tmp{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathparse{\p > 1 ? sqrt(-1) :
      (\p < 0 ? sqrt(-1) :
        \sigma@neg ? sqrt(-1) :
         (\sigma@zero ? \mu :
           (#4 ? \mu+\sigma*\@tmp :         
                     \mu-\sigma*\@tmp)
         )
       )
    }%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\samplesize{7}\relax
  \let\mean\relax\newcommand\mean{9}\relax
  \let\sd\relax\newcommand\sd{3}\relax
  \let\lowertail\relax\newcommand\lowertail{0}\relax
\begin{figure}[ht]
\capstart
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{15}
  \multiframe{15}{ik=1+2}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      hide y axis,
      axis lines*=center, 
      axis on top,
      no markers, 
      domain=4:20, 
      samples=4*\samplesize-7,
      xlabel=\empty, 
      ylabel=\empty,
      every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
      every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
      width=.8\linewidth,
      height=.3\linewidth,
      xmin = 4, xmax=20,
      xtick=, ytick=\empty,
      enlargelimits=false, 
      clip=false
  ]
  \pgfmathsetmacro\result{1/((\ik/25+.65)^2+(ln(\ik/25+.65)^2+1.5))/1.2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\static{qnorm(0.05,\mean,\sd,\lowertail)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\qqq{qnorm(\result,\mean,\sd,\lowertail)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\colorq{(.1+.2*\ik/180)*100}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\colorr{(.3+.55*\ik/180)*100}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\colort{(.9-.8*\ik/180)*100}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\colors{(.85-.55*\ik/180)*100}
  \node at (axis cs:5,0.2) {};
  \node at (axis cs:10.25,0.025) {\ifnum\ik>75{\textcolor{red}{waarschijnlijk een effect! $\rightarrow$}}\else{waarschijnlijk geen effect}\fi};
  \node at (axis cs:\qqq,{1/(\sd*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\qqq-\mean)^2)/(2*\sd^2))+.02}) {\ifnum\ik<75$\downarrow$\else\textcolor{red}{$\downarrow$}\fi}; 
  \path[name path=line] (axis cs:\static,0) -- (axis cs:\static,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}*1.1);
  \addplot [name path=normaal,very thick,cyan!85!black!50] {normal(\mean,\sd)};
  \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
  \addplot[cyan!\colort!red!\colorq,draw=cyan!\colors!red!\colorr,thick]   fill between[of=normaal and axis,soft clip={domain=\qqq:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}];
  \node at (axis cs:{\mean+1.65*\sd},{.055-.003*\sd^.5-.0015*\sd^2}) [pin=45:$\alpha$] {}; 
  \node at (axis cs:{\mean*.85},{1/(\sd*sqrt(2*pi))-.015}) [pin=135:$H_0$] {};
  \node at (axis cs:{4+\mean+1.65*\sd},{.08+.055-.003*\sd^.5-.0015*\sd^2}) [rectangle,draw=blue!60,fill=cyan!10] {\ifnum\ik<75$p=\result$\else\textcolor{red}{$p=\result$}\fi}; 
  \path[name intersections={of=line and normaal, by={interp}}];
  \draw[draw=red!80!black] (axis cs:\static,0) -- (interp);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{animateinline}
\caption{De verdeling die hoort bij een nulhypothese en een aantal mogelijke meetresultaten (weergegeven door het pijltje) - wanneer je meetresultaat erg afwijkt van de aanname waarbij er geen effect zou plaatsvinden, is er dus waarschijnlijk kans op een effect}\label{fig:p.waarde.anim}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]